# Is it possible to use database functions like dateof(now()) in a Kafka Connect Sink with KCQL?

Tags: apache-kafka-connect

I am trying to do a simple Sink from a kafka topic like `INSERT INTO table SELECT * FROM topic`
but also add a column insert_timestamp with the value of `dateof(now())`

Is using database functions like this possible in KCQL for a sink connector? Can I somehow write to my topic the function `dateof(now())` without it simply trying to write the value as a string to the column? Or will I probably need to write a custom sink connector to support this?  I would use a default value on a column but that doesn't seem to be supported by Cassandra.

Comment: Which Sink are you using? `KCQL` is specific to Kafka Connect connectors written by Landoop/Data Mountaineer.

Comment: Yeah we are using the Landoop Cassandra sink documented [here](http://lenses.stream/connectors/sink/cassandra.html).  Seems like the closest we can get is writing a custom Transform that does an Instant.now() in the apply().

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with KCQL. However, you can use [Single Message Transforms](http://kafka.apache.org/documentation.html#connect_transforms), which are part of the Apache Kafka Connect API to achieve this. For example, if you want the timestamp of the Kafka message, this config in your connector should do it:

```
"transforms":"InsertMsgTS",
"transforms.InsertMsgTS.type":"org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.InsertField$Value",
"transforms.InsertMsgTS.timestamp.field":"message_ts",
```

If you want the absolute time of insert (and not the Kafka message timestamp) then you would need to write your own Transform ([javadocs](https://kafka.apache.org/10/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/connect/transforms/Transformation.html))

Comment: Yeah Ideally we want Cassandra's time on insert, not the connect's time.  But they are close enough for our use case that it'll be OK.  We ended up using a transform and doing an Instant.now() in the apply method.  But again, would prefer the actual Cassandra function we just can't figure out how.